# Facing Problem like "Cannot select from or insert/update variable '@TableName' because it is not a table variable." in Sybase ASE

Tags: t-sql, sybase, sap-ase

I am writing a stored procedure that will get some tablename as a parameter and it will do

```
"select @TableName from @TableName"
```

But Sybase ASE SQL is not allowing me to do that. I am getting this message

> Cannot select from or insert/update variable '@TableName' because it is not a table variable.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test_result 
    @TableName VARCHAR(40)
AS 
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #Results (TableName nvarchar(370))

    INSERT INTO #Results 
        SELECT @TableName FROM @TableName 

    SELECT * FROM #Results
END

EXEC Test_result 'sometablename'
```

This will simulate my actual problem. I want to insert a tablename into a Results table if it match some condition(I haven't mention that here because I don't want to confuse you).

**Note**: I want to do a quick select query from a TableName which I passed to the stored procedure. I don't want to create again the table structure because that stored procedure may get another tablename whose table DDL is different

Could anyone provide some alternative or any solution on it ?

Comment: In T-SQL, you can't use a variable to replace the value of a table; the value must be a literal.

Comment: Is there any alternative over there ..any solution any work around please.

Comment: And one more question, Can I use @columnname dynamically in select part and where condition part ?..answers are welcome 

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know enough about SyBase to answer that. Though I will admit, wanted a dataset returned where the table name is repeated once per row in the table seems an odd requirement. Also it seems odd that `TableName` in the table `#Results` is defined as a `nvarchar(370)` when the value you are `INSERT`ing (`@TableName`) is a `varchar(40)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for delay in response. I have found myself a workaround for that which I would like to share.

```
INSERT INTO #Results select @TableName from @TableName
```

To make this working, use a variable to store this query and execute using EXEC statement in sybase.

The workaround will be,

```
BEGIN
    SET @sqlquery='INSERT INTO #Results select @TableName from @TableName '
    EXEC(@sqlquery)
END
```

This solved my problem as @tablename variable we can't directly used to replace the value of a table.

Answer (score 1):

If the objective is to insert the value of `@TableName` into `#Results` then either of the following should suffice:

```
INSERT INTO #Results select @TableName
INSERT INTO #Results values (@TableName)
```

If the intent is to insert `@TableName` into `#Results` but only if there's a user table with this name in the current database then try:

```
INSERT INTO #Results select name from sysobjects where type = 'U' and name = @TableName
```

If this doesn't answer the question then please update the question with more details as well as some examples of `@TableName` values that do and do not work.